# What is the best solution to pick up value from rigth column based on range in left column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

What is the best solution to pick up value from rigth column based on range in left column?
What is best not to use heavy loops: numpy array, pandas series, dict, list.
Data itself in Dataframe and ranges are bigger that in the example. And not only one value it could be a row with many values.

[image]

There is an Excel file that shows the tariffs for transportation depending on various conditions. Tariffs change quarterly, in this file. Old data is overwritten. Therefore, the format must be left for automatic loading into Dataframe. It is necessary to select the desired line with the tariff depending on the distance. For example For 74 km I should pick up 6955,00 if condition 1.

Comment: Will you please show a text sample of your dataframe, so I can copy/paste it?

Comment: I did not understand the problem you're trying to solve. Could you try to be more specific? Could you also post an input and the related expected output?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco. I think the OP wants for a given `x` value, find x in the `range` column and return the value from the `value` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, split your range into two other columns (left and right) then return the right value from right column if `(left <= x) & (x <= right)`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'range': ['51-60', '61-70'], 'value': [6505.00, 6730.00]})
df[['left', 'right']] = df['range'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)

get_value = lambda x: df.loc[(df['left'] <= x) & (x <= df['right']), 'value'].squeeze()

print(df)
   range   value  left  right
0  51-60  6505.0    51     60
1  61-70  6730.0    61     70
```

Usage:

```
>>> get_value(53)
6505.0

>>> get_value(70)
6730.0
```

**Update** after your edit

```
import pandas as pd

# Suppose your file is organized like:
# Dist | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4
df = pd.read_excel('Tariff.xlsx')
quarter = pd.Timestamp.today().quarter  # quarter is the column number

interval = df['Distance'].str.extractall('(?P<left>\d+)[^\d]+(?P<right>\d+)') \
             .droplevel(1).astype(int)

get_value = lambda x: df.loc[(interval['left'] <= x) & (x <= interval['right'])] \
                        .iloc[:, quarter].squeeze()
```

Comment: Would appritiate if there are other options based on updated comments.

Comment: Just tried to my situation.  Would say that perfectly fit.  Once again Thank you!